# I need to show all data form pinjaman_id but only last data in every pinjaman_id form database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using laravel, I want to make show all last data based on pinjaman_id this mean I only need last data of pinjaman_id, so pinjaman_id cant show duplicate, I just need the last one, and show them all last data with diffirent pinjaman_id

```
$pinjaman = DB::table('invoice')->where('pinjaman_id', 67)->orderBy('tgl_tempo', 'desc')->first();
```

if I'm using this, its only show last data in pinjaman_id = 67, I need to show them all but only last data based on tgl_tempo desc

```
$pinjaman = DB::table('invoice')->where('pinjaman_id', ??)->orderBy('tgl_tempo', 'desc')->first();
```

this is image my database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$query = "select * from invoice where id IN (select MAX(id) from invoice where user_id = :userId group by pinjaman_id) order by tgl_tempo desc "; 

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($query),['userId' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use raw query to get the correct data then use UNION ALL to get other data

```
$results = DB::select("(SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE pinjaman_id= 67 order by tgl_tempo DESC limit 1) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE pinjaman_id != 67)") ;
```